# Many to many - create new position to exist table in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> How to add another position to the already existing order in
>   controller MVC?
>     I tried as below but it does not work (PartialViewResult _AddPost)
>   Error message-  An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.

```
public class Order
    {   [Key] 
        public int IdOrder { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public int IdOrderAttachment { get; set; }
        public virtual OrderAttachment OrderAttachment { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Specify the date of order acceptance")]
        [Display(Name = "Date of acceptance of the order")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTimeDateOfAcceptance  { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date of completion planning")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? DateOfCompletionPlanning { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter the subject")]
        [MaxLength(200, ErrorMessage = "Name max 200 characters")]
        [Display(Name = "Subject")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
       //many to many
        public virtual ICollection<Position> PositionList { get; set; }
    }
    public class Position
    {
        [Key]
        public int IdPosition { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]
        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [UIHint("tinymce_jquery_full"), AllowHtml]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<OrderPosition> OrderList { get; set; }
    }
    //Map many to many 
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

                modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
                   .HasMany<Position>(s => s.PositionList)
                   .WithMany(c => c.OrderList)
                   .Map(cs =>
                   {
                       cs.ToTable("OrderPosition");
                       cs.MapLeftKey("IdOrder");
                       cs.MapRightKey("IdPosition");
                   });

[HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public PartialViewResult _AddPost(int IdOrder)
            {
                var findOrder = db.Order.Find(IdOrder);         
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    Position position = new Position { Description = "Test"};
                    db.Position.Attach(position);
                    findOrder.PositionList.Add(position);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                }
                return PartialView();
            }
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new `Position` or just link to existing `Position`?

Comment: Próbne utworzenie nowego elementu na zamówienie z elementami elementami. Add another item.

Comment: Not sure I follow the last comment. Anyway, in case you want to add new position **and** link, replace `db.Position.Attach(position);` with `db.Position.Add(position);`.

Comment: Ivan thanks I actually use the wrong method. Now it nicely adds a new position - thank you very much for the prompt help.